# Scrolling page left to right on mouse scroll in webextension

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, firefox-addon, extension-methods

I am trying to scroll the popup page inside the extension(basically I am doing this for firefox addon), the maximum width it allows for an extension in 600px, but I have to display 1000px image, otherwise the visibility of the image data gets compromised. I tried

```js
       const scroller = document.body;

       scroller.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
           evt.preventDefault();
           document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper').scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
       });
```

The wrapper is a div which contains all the contents and it's dimensions is same as the body's dimensions.
But this code is not responding to the scroll. Would be very much thankful if someone helps!

Comment: does it show to you the overflow bar?

Comment: Yes it does, but there's no sign of scroll event being detected, btw the scrolling function is correct right? I should prolly test it out on a normal document page.

Comment: if `evt.deltaY` has a positive value, the code is correct